# Which integer is closest to the difference?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, radicals, integers, solution-verification

> **Problem:** Which integer is closest to the difference? (Contest math)
>
> $$\large\underbrace{1000\cdots}_{2020} \thinspace-\sqrt{\underbrace{99\cdots9}_{2019}\thinspace \thinspace \underbrace{00\cdots0}_{2019}}$$

My attempts:

> $\underbrace{1000\cdots}_{2020}=10^{2019}$
>
> $\sqrt{\underbrace{99\cdots9}_{2019}\thinspace \thinspace \underbrace{00\cdots0}_{2019}}=\sqrt{\underbrace{99\cdots9}_{2019}\thinspace \thinspace \underbrace{99\cdots 9}_{2019}-\underbrace{99\cdots9}_{2019}\thinspace \thinspace }=\sqrt{10^{4038}-1-10^{2019}+1}=\sqrt{10^{2019}(10^{2019}-1)}$
>
> We have, $\underbrace{1000\cdots}_{2020} \thinspace-\sqrt{\underbrace{99\cdots9}_{2019}\thinspace \thinspace \underbrace{00\cdots0}_{2019}}=10^{2019}-\sqrt{10^{2019}(10^{2019}-1)}$

But, I can not continue from here and I don't know if my attempts are true or not.

Do my attempts correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt can be continued
$$  10^{2019} = \sqrt{10^{2019} 10^{2019}} > \sqrt{10^{2019}(10^{2019}-1)} > \sqrt{(10^{2019}-1)(10^{2019}-1)} = 10^{2019}-1  \text{,}  $$
so the closest integer to $10^{2019} - \sqrt{10^{2019}(10^{2019}-1)}$ is either $0$ or $1$.  So let's compare $10^{2019}(10^{2019}-1)$ with \begin{align*}
(10^{2019} - 1/2)^2 &= (10^{2019})^2 - 10^{2019} + 1/4  \\
&= 10^{2019}(10^{2019}-1) + 1/4  \\
&> 10^{2019}(10^{2019}-1)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
discovering that we are not subtracting enough for the result to be $1/2$, so the result is in the interval $(1/2,1)$ and $1$ is the closest integer to $10^{2019} - \sqrt{10^{2019}(10^{2019}-1)}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=1/10^{2019}$ and write what you've got as

$${1-\sqrt{1-x}\over x}={1\over1+\sqrt{1-x}}$$

It's easy to see that if $0\lt x\le1$ (which $1/10^{2019}$ certainly is), then

$$1={1\over1+\sqrt{1-1}}\ge{1\over1+\sqrt{1-x}}\gt{1\over1+\sqrt{1+0}}={1\over2}$$

so the nearest integer is $1$.

Comment: Thank you. What is the meaning of your expressions? Where it comes from?

Comment: @Elementary, which expression are you asking about?

Comment: What is the meaning of ${1-\sqrt{1-x}\over x}={1\over1+\sqrt{1-x}}$

Comment: @Elementary, it's an algebraic identity which is true for *all* $x$. Basically, I'm factoring a $10^{2019}$ out of your square root, giving $10^{2019}-10^{2019}\sqrt{1-10^{-2019}}$, and then rewriting it as $(1-\sqrt{1-10^{-2019}})/10^{-2019}$, after which the algebraic identity turns it into $1/(1+\sqrt{1-10^{-2019}})$. Part of the reason for using an $x$ is so I don't have to keep writing a bunch of $10^{-2019}$'s; another part is that it makes it clear there's nothing special, really, about the number $2019$.

Comment: Thanks your explanation. I know this is an elemantary identity. I mean it was the goal of using it.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, the inequalities $0\le x\le1$ applies to the second display, not the first.

Comment: Need to specify nonzero $x$ for the first display, forcing $0<x<1$ for the second anyway.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, I made the change you recommended, albeit for an altogether different reason: Allowing $x=0$ in $1/(1+\sqrt{1-x})$ produces a buridan's asslike dilemma in the form of the number $1/2$, which can't decide which integer it's closest to. So thank you for bringing the matter to my attention!

Answer (score 3):

Complete the square in the radicand:

$10^{2019}-\sqrt{(10^{2019})^2-10^{2019}\color{blue}{+(1/4)}}=10^{2019}-(10^{2019}-(1/2))=(1/2)$

Infer that the closest integer to your actual defference, with the radicand being $1/4$ less, is slightly greater than $1/2$ and get the closest integer accordingly.

Comment: 1) Do my attepmts correct? Could you check it? 2) So the answer equals to $0$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand the first line.

Comment: How can we prove $10^{2019}-\sqrt{(10^{2019})^2-10^{2019}\color{blue}{+(1/4)}}<1$

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratic-functions-equations/x2f8bb11595b61c86:completing-square-quadratics/v/solving-quadratic-equations-by-completing-the-square

Comment: you fixed $\frac 12$. Then I understood.